# Flash, AS3 -> TweenLite + Box2D - do they combine?

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d, gsap

Well, imagine the scenario where i have 3 objects, hanging from the "ceiling", each one by a string (inside a b2World).  They are touching each other side by side.
Each object has a Flash Mouse_Over event that makes itself use tweenlite to scale bigger, and Mouse_Out it scales back to the original size.

My question is: do the other two objects respond to those TweenLite animations, using the Box2D motor?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: Sort of.

Box2D objects do not scale. But you can make it appear that they do.

Here is a great tutorial walking you through exactly how to do that:
http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/12/16/scaling-objects-with-box2d-part-2/